# How do I pass command line arguments to a Lambda function in Serverless/Bref?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless, bref

I am running a Symfony 4 (PHP) application on AWS Lambda using Bref (which uses Serverless).

Bref provides a layer for Symfony's bin/console binary. The Serverless config for the Lambda function looks like this:

```
functions:
    console:
        handler: bin/console
        name: 'mm-console'
        description: 'Symfony 4 console'
        timeout: 120 # in seconds
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-73} # PHP
            - ${bref:layer.console} # The "console" layer
```

Using the above, I can run `vendor/bin/bref cli mm-console -- mm:find-matches` to run `bin/console mm:find-matches` on Lambda.

What if I want to run the `mm:find-matches` console command on a schedule on Lambda?
I tried this:

```
functions:
    mm-find-matches:
        handler: "bin/console mm:find-matches"
        name: 'mm-find-matches'
        description: 'Find mentor matches'
        timeout: 120
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-73} # PHP
            - ${bref:layer.console} # The "console" layer
        schedule:
            rate: rate(2 hours)
```

However "`bin/console mm:find-matches`" is not a valid handler.
How can I pass `mm:find-matches` command to the `bin/console` function on a schedule?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass command line arguments via the schedule event input like so:

```
functions:
    console:
        handler: bin/console
        name: 'mm-console'
        description: 'Symfony 4 console'
        timeout: 120 # in seconds
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-73} # PHP
            - ${bref:layer.console} # The "console" layer
        events:
            - schedule:
                input:
                    cli: "mm:find-matches --env=test"
                rate: rate(2 hours)
                enabled: true
```

Although there is some discussion on [this bref github issue](https://github.com/brefphp/bref/issues/339) about whether using the cli console application is the best solution, vs writing PHP functions that bootstrap the kernel and do the specific thing you want the command to do.